# How to draw circle inside a circle using pie chart in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, charts, mpandroidchart

[image: I want to create chart same as shown in image.]

I want to create a pie or slice chart in android application. I have searched out various libraries but none of them draw two circles like shown in the picture. I have attached a sample picture of chart. Any suggestion about this will be very helpful for me. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What you had tried? and also share the code

Comment: @Sniffer I have not done anything yet still trying to find some suitable library for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one **github** Library where you can draw different types of graph.
You can add this **dependency** to your **gradle**

```
 implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
```

For more information this is the **Link:** https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
            android:id="@+id/piechart_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300sp">
        </com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Activity** :

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

        protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
{
          super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.Your_layout);
          setPieChart(); }

         public void setPieChart() {
                    this.pieChart = pieChart;
                    pieChart.setUsePercentValues(true);
                    pieChart.getDescription().setEnabled(true);
                    pieChart.setExtraOffsets(5,10,5,5);
                    pieChart.setDragDecelerationFrictionCoef(0.9f);
                    pieChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(61f);
                    pieChart.setHoleColor(Color.WHITE);
                    pieChart.animateY(1000, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInOutCubic);
                    ArrayList<PieEntry> yValues = new ArrayList<>();
                    yValues.add(new PieEntry(34f,"Ilala"));
                    yValues.add(new PieEntry(56f,"Temeke"));
                    yValues.add(new PieEntry(66f,"Kinondoni"));
                    yValues.add(new PieEntry(45f,"Kigamboni"));

                    PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yValues, "Desease Per 
                     Regions");
                    dataSet.setSliceSpace(3f);
                    dataSet.setSelectionShift(5f);
                    dataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
                    PieData pieData = new PieData((dataSet));
                    pieData.setValueTextSize(10f);
                    pieData.setValueTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    pieChart.setData(pieData);
                    //PieChart Ends Here
                }
}
```